# "haven't got ANY apples" vs. "haven't got apples"

Tags: word-usage

Is the phrase *"We have not got apples."* correct, or we must use  *We have not got **any** apples.* instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can say you haven't got [noun plural or a plus noun singular]. In the plural or singular.

We have no apples.
We haven't got apples.

"We haven't got any apples" can be used also.

[We have not got is usually shortened to: we haven't got, in speech]

"Have you got any apples?" can mean the person asking thinks the answer **may be** negative as the person cannot see any apples in the shop/store.

Comment: Are there any differences between  "We haven't got apples." and  "We haven't got any apples."?

Comment: @rhymer1987 I explained it. It's about the **expectation**, as I explained. Have you got any questions? Expectation: The person asking the question expects there to be questions.

Comment: I would just note that another common form for negated possession is "don't have."  The implication of using or not using "any" in a sentence such as "we don't have [any] apples" is probably the same.  But @rhymer1987 is asking about a statement, not a question.  Is expectation the governing factor there?  Are there other factors that would influence the inclusion or omission of "any"?  It seems to me that there probably are, but I can't think of examples at the moment.

Comment: @phoog Two present tenses, same meaning: have got//have. But that was not the question. One doesn't usually go around saying things like: We don't have [have got] **any apples** unless one has been asked a question or it looks like the person is asking it without asking it.

Comment: Maybe I'm just chipping away at some unimportant degree of imprecision in the choice of the word "expectation," but if someone asked me to list things that I don't have in my apartment, I think I would be just as likely to say "I don't have any elephants" as I would "I don't have elephants," or even somewhat more likely.  Surely there's no expectation of elephants being in my apartment?

Comment: @phoog You are clearly  not understanding me. any versus the null set is not exactly the same discursively.